# ListView onItemLongClick view isSelected always returns False

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter, onlongclicklistener

I have a class that extends `ListFragment` and uses a `SimpleCursorAdapter`. I have created 2 buttons that enables the user to select/deselect all in the list and this works fine. There could be 200 items in the list, so if they wanted to only select 190 of them, they could select all 200 then deselect 10.

The ListView uses `setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);`

The problem is that I want the user to be able to individually deselect a row by long pressing the row. I use a `setOnItemLongClickListener` on the `ListView` but the `view.isSelected` is always returning `false` even when the row is selected.

Does anyone know why this is happening.

I've put log statements in to prove this fact.

I have also had a look around the net and some posts are saying that a possible problem is that I am using `SimpleCursorAdapter` and that it is too basic a component.

I'm not particularly good with adapters, lists and touch events, so could anyone point me in the right direction?

I suppose the obvious thing to tackle, is why the isSelected method always returns false.

```
public  class  CarerListForGroupMessageFragment extends ListFragment {

    private static final String TAG =  CarerListForGroupMessageFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    RROnCallApplication rrOnCallApp;
    Cursor cursor;
    ListView listView;
    MyAdapter myAdapter;
    OnCarerForGroupMessageSelectedListener mListener;
    EditText etext;
    Button resetSearch;
    Button selectAll;
    Button deselectAll;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        rrOnCallApp = (RROnCallApplication) getActivity().getApplicationContext();

        cursor = getCarerList(null);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentcarerlistforgroupmessage, container, false);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        String[] from = new String[]{DBModel.C_CARER_FIRSTNAME, DBModel.C_CARER_LASTNAME, DBModel.C_CARER_PHONENUMBER};
        int[] to = {R.id.carerrowfirstname, R.id.carerrowlastname, R.id.carerrowtelno};

        myAdapter = (MyAdapter) new MyAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.carerrow , cursor, from, to);

        setListAdapter(myAdapter);
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        getListView().setFastScrollEnabled(true);
        getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);    

selectAll = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.carerlistselectallgroupmessage);
        selectAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {    
                for(int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++){
                    getListView().setItemChecked(i, true);
                }

                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        deselectAll = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.carerlistdeselectallgroupmessage);
        deselectAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for(int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
                    getListView().setItemChecked(i, false);
                }

                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

 getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "On long click listener", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                boolean ret = false;
                if(! view.isSelected()) {

                    //row in list is not currently selected, so set it as selected
                    Log.e(TAG, "row postion " + position + " in list is not currently selected");

                    view.setSelected(true);

                    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) getListAdapter().getItem(position);

                    String carerID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBModel.C_CARER_ID));
                    String carerFirstName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBModel.C_CARER_FIRSTNAME));
                    String carerLastName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBModel.C_CARER_LASTNAME));
                    String carerTelNo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBModel.C_CARER_PHONENUMBER));

                    Log.e(TAG, "carerID = " + carerID);

                    mListener.onCarerForGroupMessageSelected(carerID, carerFirstName, carerLastName, carerTelNo, true);

                    getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
                    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    ret = true;

                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "row " + position + " in list is currently selected");

                    view.setSelected(false);

                    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) getListAdapter().getItem(position);

                    String carerID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBModel.C_CARER_ID));
                    String carerFirstName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBModel.C_CARER_FIRSTNAME));
                    String carerLastName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBModel.C_CARER_LASTNAME));
                    String carerTelNo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBModel.C_CARER_PHONENUMBER));

                    Log.e(TAG, "carerID = " + carerID);

                    mListener.onCarerForGroupMessageSelected(carerID, carerFirstName, carerLastName, carerTelNo, true);

                    getListView().setItemChecked(position, false);
                    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    ret = true;
                }

                return  ret;
            }
        });
    } // End of onActivityCreated


// Container Activity must implement this interface
public interface OnCarerForGroupMessageSelectedListener {
    public void onCarerForGroupMessageSelected(String carerId, String carerFirstName, String carerLastName, String carerTelNo ,boolean longClick);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnCarerForGroupMessageSelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnCarerForGroupMessageSelectedListener");
    }
}

 @Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Log.e(TAG, "in onListItemClick");
    v.setSelected(true);

    //v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));

    TextView carerName = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textviewcarername);

    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) getListAdapter().getItem(position);

    String carerID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBModel.C_CARER_ID));
    String carerFirstName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBModel.C_CARER_FIRSTNAME));
    String carerLastName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBModel.C_CARER_LASTNAME));
    String carerTelNo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBModel.C_CARER_PHONENUMBER));

    Log.e(TAG, "carerID = " + carerID);

    mListener.onCarerForGroupMessageSelected(carerID, carerFirstName, carerLastName, carerTelNo, false);

    getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private class MyAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public MyAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    }

    @Override
    public
    View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.e(TAG, "inside myadapter getview");
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        if(v == null)
            return null;

        Log.e(TAG, "clicked the listview!");

        //Cursor c = (Cursor)getItem(position);
        // String tagScanTime = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(LoginValidate.C_TAG_SCAN_TIME));

        // ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.rowcarername)).setText(name + " signed " + status +" at ");

        return v;
    }
}} //end of CarerListFragment
```

[EDIT 1]

DBModel class

```
public class DBModel {



    private static final String TAG = DBModel.class.getSimpleName();





    // table carer column names
        public static final String C_CARER_ID_INDEX = BaseColumns._ID;
        public static final String C_CARER_ID = "carerid";
        public static final String C_CARER_FIRSTNAME = "carerfirstname";
        public static final String C_CARER_LASTNAME = "carerlastname";
        public static final String C_CARER_PHONENUMBER = "carerphonenumber";
        public static final String C_CARER_EMAIL = "careremail";




Context context;
    DBHelper dbhelper;
    RROnCallApplication rrOnCallApplication;



    public DBModel(Context context) {

        this.context = context;
        dbhelper = new DBHelper();
        rrOnCallApplication = (RROnCallApplication) context.getApplicationContext();


    }






/**
     * inner class to create/open/upgrade database
     * 
     * @author matt
     * 
     */
    private class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        // database name and version number
        public static final String DB_NAME = "roadrunneroncall.db";
        public static final int DB_VERSION = 3;

        // table names


        public static final String TABLECARER = "carer";


        public DBHelper() {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            Log.e(TAG, "SQLiteOpenHelper oncreate ");



String sqlToCreateCarerTable = String
                    .format("create table %s ( %s INTEGER primary key, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT)",
                            TABLECARER, C_CARER_ID_INDEX, C_CARER_ID, C_CARER_FIRSTNAME,
                            C_CARER_LASTNAME, C_CARER_PHONENUMBER, C_CARER_EMAIL);

            db.execSQL(sqlToCreateCarerTable);
            Log.e(TAG, "oncreate " + sqlToCreateCarerTable);

}




        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {





        }//end of onUpgrade

    }//end of DBHelper


public  SQLiteDatabase getDB(){

        return dbhelper.getWritableDatabase(RROnCallApplication.getSecretKey().toString());

    }



public void deleteTableCarer() {
        // open database
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase(RROnCallApplication.getSecretKey().toString());

        // delete contents of table
        db.delete(DBHelper.TABLECARER, null, null);

        // close database
        // db.close();
    }


    public void insertIntoCarer(ContentValues cv) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase(RROnCallApplication.getSecretKey().toString());

        db.insertWithOnConflict(DBHelper.TABLECARER, null, cv, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);

        // db.close();

    }



    public Cursor queryAllFromCarer() {

        // open database
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase(RROnCallApplication.getSecretKey().toString());

        return db.query(DBHelper.TABLECARER, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    }
```

Comment: all you can do is Create a Model class and add boolean flag in it name it as is selected and then on selection set and get this method to check if it is already selected or not. and on long press set boolean as selected true. and updated list row.!

Comment: Do not use view.isSelected if you can not trust it. `getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);`. Before you set true or false just check if item is checked or not and then reverse.

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi Hi so could i use a data structure like a hashmap where the key is the position. i think i have done this before when using checkboxes in a row.

Comment: If you  will create model class then its easy for you because when you will click each object you will get whether its was selected or not .!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this code.

`if(!getListView().isItemChecked(position))`

instead of

`if(! view.isSelected())`

And keep boolean flag value inside DBModel class.

Comment: Hi, there is no isSelected method when i use this code.

Comment: Please add boolean flag isSelected or any meaningful named inside your DBModel class and make two public method 

setslected(boolean) and boolean isSelected()

when you are selecting any view that time inside your model flag need to make true and vice versa

Comment: Hi. Sorry but i do not understand some of what you say. I understand that you want me you keep a flag in my database model class that refects the state but getListView().getAdapter().getItem(position).isSelected() is expecting an isSelected method in the Adapter class. it is not there. sorry if i am missing your point. could you share a basic code example?

Comment: ah wait, sorry, getListView().getAdapter().getItem(position).isSelected() returns a cursor with the rows. so you mean add a row to my DB table that holds isSelected?

Comment: I have update above answer.

You need to keep just one flag do not need to save it inside your database if it's just temporary.

You need to keep this flag as just one field inside that class

Comment: No @tortleboy,

I am just telling you to keep one new flag boolean typed field inside your DBModel class

DBModel class is created by you right?

Comment: i've edited the post (EDIT 1). this shows my DBModel class with 90% removed, just shows the parts that are relevant. The table that feeds the listview is the carer table. this table is used elsewhere in the application so i do not want to modify the table. i not saying you are asking me to either. could you show me want you mean please?

Comment: Hello @turtleboy,

I can understand what I suggest you it's not possible in this case because what I suggest you for that you need to keep one model bean class for that.

It's different your case.

Please check above updated code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168294/discussion-between-sameer-jani-and-turtleboy).

Comment: Hi mate, that worked great. Thanks for your help on this! :)

Comment: Welcome buddy :)